# How i can get a percentage to coincidence with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have my model and my bias and when I predict my image I get a a vector like this

[0 , 0 , 0 , 1]

and I need something like this

[.48, .52, .08, .97]

my training  code is:

```
entrenamiento_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rescale=1. / 255,
shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

entrenamiento_generador = entrenamiento_datagen.flow_from_directory(
data_entrenamiento,
target_size=(altura, longitud),
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode='categorical')

validacion_generador = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
data_validacion,
target_size=(altura, longitud),
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode='categorical')

cnn = Sequential()
cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtrosConv1, tamano_filtro1, padding ="same",input_shape=(longitud, altura, 3), activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=tamano_pool))

cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtrosConv2, tamano_filtro2, padding ="same"))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=tamano_pool))

cnn.add(Flatten())
cnn.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))
cnn.add(Dense(clases, activation='sigmoid'))

cnn.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=lr),
        metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and  my classification code is:

```
ongitud, altura = 150, 150
modelo = './modelo/modelo.h5'
pesos_modelo = './modelo/pesos.h5'
with CustomObjectScope({'GlorotUniform': glorot_uniform()}):
cnn = load_model(modelo)
cnn.load_weights(pesos_modelo)

def predict(file):
  x = load_img(file, target_size=(longitud, altura))
  x = img_to_array(x)
  x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
  array = cnn.predict_proba(x[0:1])
  print(array)
```

I have tried with predict(), predict_proba() but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You should use binary_crossentropy instead of categorical_crossentropy:

- categorical_crossentropy is used for multi-class problems, i.e. choosing one class out of many for each sample. It returns a vectors of numbers between 0 and 1 which sums to 1.
- binary_crossentropy is used for multi-label problems, i.e. assigning possibly more than one label to each sample. It returns a vector of numbers, each between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

For each image, if only one out of the 4 labels is correct(similar to ImageNet) then the activation in the final layer should be softmax.

```
cnn.add(Dense(clases, activation='softmax'))
```

This way the sum of probabilities will be equal to 1 and you can select the class with highest probability. e.g. this is the output using cnn.predict() or cnn.predict_proba()(both the outputs are same).

[0.09843186 0.613065   0.19164166 0.09686147]

cnn.predict_classes() will give the class, in this case, [1].